Integration scorm in laravel 10
I have a project in Laravel 10 and I'm trying to get student iteration data in scorm 1.2
some points.

I already have the scorm working. If you open your index.html it will work normally
Sends requests and presents these requests in the console to receive/send to the bank (sco)

However, I have no idea how this communication with the bank is constructed.
From what I understand, scorm itself sends the information when launching the game. What I would need was to "read" them. but how?
Searching chatGP4 he said that I needed a wrapper.js to be a bridge between scorm play and the laravel backend.
the file that implements it, but doesn't evolve anything: https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper/blob/master/src/JavaScript/SCORM_API_wrapper.js
Can anyone tell me if I'm not on the right path or if I'm wrong?
My goal is to have a "play" that brings information from the student's iteration such as:
His name
what time he entered the course, left, how much per center he completed, how many attempts he made mistakes, etc...

SCORM high level requirements -

SCORM Content that communicates with SCORM 1.2 or 2004
LMS able to import Zip or other option and parse imsmanifest.xml
LMS or like implementation with SCORM Runtime capable of generating a clean student attempt or serving up a persisted suspended attempt.

ChatGPT may get you part of the way there these days.  I have an open source content API at https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot and a paid option on cybercussion.com as it took a few years to get that refined.
I believe the 'wrapper' you linked is for content.  I'm unaware of any highly functioning SCORM Runtime APIs that are free.  Can you roll your own?  Sure just plan on it taking ~ 1-2 years which ChatGPT may be able to help you shorten and maybe also steer you into an unintended outcome.
Note, the open source link I mentioned has a horrible sample implementation for local Runtime testing.  It is not the real thing just empty vessel to spoof it.  But can be used for inspiration.
Both SCORM 1.2 and 2004 had white papers from ADL.  SCORM 2004 is infinitely more challenging due to Sequence and Navigation.  All these concepts really required deep Authoring and content creation tied directly to publishing content packages that can function on a LMS that supported these features.
